# Echo is not defined Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-echo

I am trying to set up event broadcasting with Laravel 5.4 + Redis + Sockets + Echo but I'm running into a problem. I've run:

```
npm install --save laravel-echo
```

I've put the following at the bottom of my resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js file:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

I've then run the following to compile everything:

```
npm run dev
```

I am including the compiled app.js file in the head and trying to listen like so :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang=en> 
<head> 
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="epkZXByjsW4lU6wwD2mELWe60Q26m3642lvMCoLK">
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/js/app.js"></script>
        </head> 
    <body>

        <h1>Chat</h1>

        <script src="//localhost:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Echo.private('chat')
                .listen('MessageSentEvent', (e) => {
                    console.log(e.update);
                });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the console I get the following two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrfToken' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 2b5c37a…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 2b5c37a…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (module.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 2b5c37a…:19)
    at bootstrap 2b5c37a…:65
    at bootstrap 2b5c37a…:65
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.js:24
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 2b5c37a…:19
(anonymous) @ app.js:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 2b5c37a…:19
(anonymous) @ module.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 2b5c37a…:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 2b5c37a…:65
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 2b5c37a…:65
chat:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined
    at chat:36
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your bootstrap.js

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you defined `window.Echo`, not `Echo`.

To access it, do this instead:

```
window.Echo.channel()....
```

At chat line 36 change this:

```
Echo.private('chat')
    .listen('MessageSentEvent', (e) => {
        console.log(e.update);
    });
```

To this:

```
window.Echo.private('chat')
    .listen('MessageSentEvent', (e) => {
        console.log(e.update);
    });
```

Hope this fixes your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention that upon which event you are getting that error on console.

These may help:

https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/68
https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/65

It looks like you are trying to create a chat application. I recently built such chat app using Laravel 5.4 + Redis + Sockets + Echo:

https://github.com/xparthx/laravel-realtime-chat

It will help you to build your own once you check that.

Thanks